# Create dataframe with repeating string from scratch in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a dataframe that essentially would look something like this
[image]

Repeating the period from 1 to 10 and assigning the ID 42,574 times
so that I would end up with a 425,740 row dataframe.

I tried to create a dataframe using the following code

```
periodstring <- as.numeric(gl(10, 42574))
periods <- as.data.frame(periodstring)
```

but that sorts the numbers and other approaches did not quiete work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `expand.grid(Period = 1:10, id = 1:42574)`

Comment: that works, thanks, if you post it as an answer I can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option using `rep`:

```
data.frame(Period=rep(1:10,times=42574),
           ID=rep(1:42574,each=10))
```

Output sample:

```
    Period ID
1        1  1
2        2  1
3        3  1
4        4  1
5        5  1
6        6  1
7        7  1
8        8  1
9        9  1
10      10  1
11       1  2
12       2  2
13       3  2
14       4  2
15       5  2
16       6  2
17       7  2
18       8  2
19       9  2
20      10  2
```